# SF3 - Add entity name with JmsSerializer

Tags: json, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I'm using Symfony 3, FosRestBundle and JsmSerializerBundle.

I want to add the entity name in my json response.

Exemple:

```
{
  'user':
    {
      'id': 0
      'firstName': 'John',
      'lastName': 'Doe',
      'posts': [
        {
          'id': 0,
          'name': 'post name #1'
        },
        {
          'id': 1,
          'name': 'post name #2'
        },
      ]
    }
}
```

Where 'user' is an entity User and post an entity Post.

What's the best way to build my json ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your json is not valid 'posts' can be object `{}` instead of array `[]`, and duplicated key 'post' is not allowed.

In order to get the type of each entity can add a property in each entity for that.

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @Serializer\Expose()
 */
private $entityType = 'user';
```

...and your json looks like:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "entityType": "user",
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "entityType": "post",
      "name": "post name #1"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "entityType": "post",
      "name": "post name #2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Edit1: Create a response object to wrap the entity

```
class GetUserResponse
{
    /**
     * @var User
     * @Serializer\Expose()
     * @Serializer\SerializedName(name="user")
     */
    protected $user;
}
```

should return

```
{
  'user':
    //.... 
 }
```

Comment: I have edited my json to correct the post/posts. entityType could be a solution. I preferre to have the entityType outside the entity data. Is that possible ? Maybe with a Normalizer ?

Comment: With this modification the only that you need is user type, because the others (posts) get the name based on the property, in this case you can simple wrap your return before send to the consumer, see @edit1 in the above response